# Nested for loop using lambda function

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have a nested for loop something like:

```py
for x in df['text']:
  for i in x:
    if i in someList:
      count++
```

Where `df['text']` is a series of lists containing words such as `['word1', 'word2', 'etc']`
I know I can just use the `for` format but I want to convert it into a lambda function.
I tried doing:
`df['in'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: [count++ for i in x if i in someList])`
but it is not proper syntax. How can I modify to get the function to what I desire?

Comment: can you add a sample data and an expected output so we don't have to guess. Will be useful for future readers too..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel like you need expend the row and doing with `isin` , since with pandas , we usually try not use for loop .

```
df['in']=pd.DataFrame(df['text'].tolist(),index=df.index).isin(someList).sum(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any additional functions. Just create a sequences of ones (one per element) to sum.

```
count = sum(1 for x in df['text'] for i in x if i in someList)
```

Comment: @OP also possibly faster to use a set instead of `someList`

Comment: Is this output one value or list ?

Comment: It's one value; no new lists are created. A generator expression is passed to `sum`.

Comment: I should note that I have another column in my df, 'count', where the count for each text is placed into. The provided code sums up all of the counts I believe because my 'count' column contains all the same number, 60085.

Answer (score 2):

#### Setup

```
someList = [*'ABCD']
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(text=[*map(list, 'AB CD AF EG BH IJ ACDE'.split())]))

df

           text
0        [A, B]
1        [C, D]
2        [A, F]
3        [E, G]
4        [B, H]
5        [I, J]
6  [A, C, D, E]
```

---

#### Numpy and `__contains__`

```
i = np.arange(len(df)).repeat(df.text.str.len())
a = np.zeros(len(df), int)
np.add.at(a, i, [*map(someList.__contains__, np.concatenate(df.text))])
df.assign(**{'in': a})

           text  in
0        [A, B]   2
1        [C, D]   2
2        [A, F]   1
3        [E, G]   0
4        [B, H]   1
5        [I, J]   0
6  [A, C, D, E]   3
```

---

#### `map` `lambda` and `__contains__`

```
df.assign(**{'in': df.text.map(lambda x: sum(map(someList.__contains__, x)))})

           text  in
0        [A, B]   2
1        [C, D]   2
2        [A, F]   1
3        [E, G]   0
4        [B, H]   1
5        [I, J]   0
6  [A, C, D, E]   3
```